# Parsing, reformating log file using sed or perhaps a script?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu, sed

I have a case, a file which I need to `post-process`. The sample format is given below:-

```
bigspeedpro.com Intel::DOMAIN   from http://malc0de.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
1.1.1.1 Intel::DOMAIN   from http://abcd.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
```

Expected output is :--

```
1.1.1.1 abcd
```

Parsing is as:-

- Anything which doesn't start with IP address delete that line
- If start with IP address do

  - delete Intel::DOMAIN
  - between  `from`  to  `F` replace it based upon following strings occurrences
  - e.g malc0de or abcd

I want to use, sed but I don't know If `sed` can be used to match multiple strings e.g malc0de or abc perhaps I need a more complete script then just one-liner storing strings values in array. Any idea? By the way, examples using `sed` be most welcomed.

So far

- I know using `d` in sed I can delete the line and redirect output to a file
- I know how to match a regex for not IP address [^a-zA-Z]
- **I'm stuck in replacing based upon multiple choice or strings**

> ```
> \#!/bin/bash          
> sed -i s/\[a-zA-Z]\/d test ./infile > testme.txt
> sed -i s/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/s+\Intel::DOMAIN\\s*from(.*?)\s+F\1malc0de
> ```

Or I'm thinking of saving like ARRAY=(malc0de abcd)

then in place of capturing group I can do ${ARRAY[2]} will it work?Or I can do something Like in .net substring match between  `from` and `F` I copy result in string variable. Then search it for my strings e.g malc0de if do find replace the searched pattern with matched result? But I don't know bash...

**update**
With the awk script I'm this clean

> ```
> 1.1.1.1 www.abc.com
> 1.1.2.2 def.com
> 2.2.2.2 mnx.dbc.net
> ```

However, I want second column after ip address to be shortened to a string of my own choice for e.g in second column I only accept

> abc
>   def
>   mnx

Once, its found just replace entire string as

```
1.1.1.1 abc
1.1.2.2 def
2.2.2.2 mnx
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you could put your expected output for the given data it would make it simple for others to understand

Comment: @Marged See update kindly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned that `sed` solutions are most welcome, but I believe `awk` would be most easy to use for your particular task. Here's my solution:

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]/ { printf $1; gsub (/http\:\/\//," "); gsub(/\.com/," ");printf " "$4"\n"  }' inputFile.txt
```

The idea is simple: by default `awk` has field separator that is blank space and allows printing specific fields, thus first we match lines that start with an ip address (four digit-dot alternating patterns); we print first field, then get rid of `https` and `.com` parts, and the domain name is the only thing that is left , thus becomes filed 4, which we print next. The rest is not specified to be printed , hence ignored.

If you want the original file to be edited, `awk` however has a quirk in that it cannot do in-line editing, unless that's `gawk` (GNU awk), so use temp file for that purpose.

Demo:

my input file

```
xieerqi:$ cat inputFile.txt                                               
bigspeedpro.com Intel::DOMAIN   from http://malc0de.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
1.1.1.1 Intel::DOMAIN   from http://abcd.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F

whatever.com Intel::DOMAIN   from http://malc0de.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
2.2.2.2 Intel::DOMAIN   from http://asdf.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
```

Command with temp file transfer (notice my inputFile.txt is in my home directory, adjust that part accordingly). NOTE: always always always have backup of the original file just in case! Or run the first part of the command before `&&` , check temp file, and if you like it, cat the file into the original one.

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]/ { printf $1; gsub (/http\:\/\//," "); gsub(/\.com/," ");printf " "$4"\n"  }' inputFile.txt > /tmp/temp.txt && cat /tmp/temp.txt > $HOME/inputFile.txt
```

output after the command ran:

```
xieerqi:$ awk '/^[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]/ { printf $1; gsub (/http\:\/\//," "); gsub(/\.com/," ");printf " "$4"\n"  }' inputFile.txt > /tmp/temp.txt && cat /tmp/temp.txt > $HOME/inputFile.txt


xieerqi:$ cat inputFile.txt                                                                                                                           
1.1.1.1 abcd
2.2.2.2 asdf
```

**Simplification through scripting**

The above command can be placed into a script with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*/ { 
printf $1; 

gsub (/http\:\/\//," "); 
gsub (/https\:\/\//," "); 
gsub(/\.com/," ");
printf " "$4"\n";
}
```

Notice that in the script I've considered possibility of multiple digits in an ip address as well as possibility of `https` in the address.

Remember to make script executable with `chmod 755 /path/to/script`

Here's the demo:

```
xieerqi:$ chmod 755 ipanddomain.awk                                                                                                                   

xieerqi:$ cat inputFile.txt                                                                                                                           
bigspeedpro.com Intel::DOMAIN   from http://malc0de.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
1.1.1.1 Intel::DOMAIN   from http://abcd.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F

whatever.com Intel::DOMAIN   from http://malc0de.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
192.168.0.2 Intel::DOMAIN   from https://asdf.foobar.whatever.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F

xieerqi:$ ./ipanddomain.awk inputFile.txt                                                                                                             
1.1.1.1 abcd
192.168.0.2 asdf.foobar.whatever
```

To edit the original file, use the trick with redirection to temp file and back to original like I showed you before

**Edit #2**

So you've asked: can simply matching part of the domain name that you already know be just printed. I've edited my script a little bit. Basically, this version looks for pattern in the $4 field and if it finds it, it goes "OK, that string has abcd in it, so I'll just print that"

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

/^[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*/ { 
printf $1" ";
matchDomain($4);
}

function matchDomain(str){

if (str~/foobar/)
 printf "foobar\n";
if(str~/abcd/)
 printf "abcd\n"

}
```

Comment: thats excellent, I didn't know such versatile syntax for awk, I'm only stuck on part of URL, the thing Is that file be written pulled from online and the format of url can by anything as long as it complies with RFC standards for e.g in case of sub domains abc.cdy.com how will the extraction work?

Comment: As long as there is no blank space anywhere between `http:` and `.com` (which considering that it's a web address, there shouldn't be any), the whole domain will be still treated as $4, so in other words, there shouldn't be any issues. Let me edit my answer to include that, will be back soon

Comment: Are the IP addresses all with one digit ? or could there be an address such as `192.168.0.25` ?

Comment: Ok, I improved my answer, simplified it a bit and made it consider ip address with multiple digits as well as possibility of `https` there.

Comment: interestingly all is well untill i got new entries similar format but still failing . Here are new entries. See question update

Comment: great with the script its parsing all lines:)

Comment: Awesome , glad to help ! So, if my answer has solved your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey check mark next to the up/down arrows. Thank you !

Comment: You don't have to say it:) It my duty you helped me a lot. One thing $4 does sometimes gives a long output i.e  wget-mirrors.uceprotect.net/rbldnsd-all/dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net.gz I'm ideally thinking just single string after IP address followed by space. So in your script what I already know what to search for and If that string is present replace the entire long domain name with single string? can it be done.

Comment: Yes, it gave long output because it only cuts off .com part. We need to add gsub command to cut .net part as well. And search and replace for a known string can be done. Just provide an example plz

Comment: @Serg I tested the script in prod 50k lines it worked well it stopped at this line 212.82.99.181/search/srpcache?p=deutsche+bank&fr=ipad&ei=UTF-8&u=http:%2F%2Fcc.bingj.com%2Fcache.aspx?q=deutsche+bank&d=4646236969304432&mkt=de-DE&setlang=d$. I have no control over format of this file, there are few roadblocks that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Serg Also, I'm not sure what you mean above when you asked all IP are in one digits, no they are not they can be anything as long its valid IP format.

Comment: @Serg I got the idea thank for edit #2  but script is failing for this log line  212.82.99.181/search/srpcache?p=deutsche+bank&fr=ipad&ei=UTF-8&u=http:%2F%2Fcc.b‌​ingj.com%2Fcache.aspx?q=deutsche+bank&d=4646236969304432&mkt=de-DE&setlang=d$.

Comment: @asad What is the full address of that website ?

Comment: @Serg Its complete address, like as it appear in log file, I copied as it is. I want to avoid that.

Comment: @asad in that case your log file has an issue . . .Address would be `example.com`.What I see there is the stuff that comes after the domain and extension, like `https://www.google.com/search?num=50&site=&source=hp&q=hello&oq=hello&gs_l=hp.3..0i131l3j0l5j0i131l2.5366.5931.0.6192.7.7.0.0.0.0.117.662.4j3.7.0..2..0...1.1.64.hp..2.5.503.0.jErZTSygP_s`.  I can certainly add a portion to the code that separates ` 212.82.99.181` but that's not the main issue, the main issue is why log file gives such error

Comment: @Serg I want bypass I have no problem reading the file with sed, how logs are written is not in my control.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand. Bypass what ?

Comment: Like escape the line which gives trouble? Don't parse it skip it. Move to next.

Answer (score 2):

Try out this small guy:

```
sed -nE 's/(^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}) .* [htpsw:\/.]{4,8}([0-9a-z.]+)\.com.*$/\1 \2/p' > newfile
```

Idea is to use grouping `()`, define proper groups and than replace matched lines with groups only using `\1 \2` etc. `-n p` combination is used to display only replaced lines and lines are replaced only if match the pattern. If you want to keep not matching lines as well remove `-n p`

> Input file:

```
bigspeedpro.com Intel::DOMAIN   from http://malc0de.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
1.1.1.1 Intel::DOMAIN   from http://abcd.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
bigspeedpro.com Intel::DOMAIN   from http://malc0de.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
123.1.1.1 Intel::DOMAIN   from http://abcd12.bcd.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
bigspeedpro.com Intel::DOMAIN   from https://malc0de.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
87.1.4.1 Intel::DOMAIN   from http://abcdtdd.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
bigspeedpro.com Intel::DOMAIN   from http://malc0de.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
192.168.1.1 Intel::DOMAIN   from www.abcdbc12a.bdf12.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
```

> Output newfile:

```
1.1.1.1 abcd
123.1.1.1 abcd12.bcd
87.1.4.1 abcdtdd
192.168.1.1 abcdbc12a.bdf12
```

**Update:** I updated my answer, changed sed a little bit, now it can handle `http/https/www` and will return what in between `https/https/www` and `.com`. And it still relatively short onliner.

Comment: I'm small?? where lmao. Anyway @BigOldTree you one liner almost worked but I don't want the problem is that these domains names come up with any variable RFC format e.g http://www.msn.com or www.msn.com or further abc.xyz.com? There i was thinking matching with pre-known domains names were better.

Comment: small guy is the sed i wrote :) yeah you can change second group to what you need, i think you got the idea.

Comment: @BigOldTree Thanks I have very nice for help